# -fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bitcode

Recently i downloaded xcode 7 beta and facing the error:

-fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0

Is there any work around to fix this issue with out changing deployment target?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you consider removing support for iOS 5. Most of the libraries are going to be built with bitcode now. Disabling bitcode would mean that you can't support Watch OS

Comment: @Gautam: Watch OS need separate libs that are build for Watch OS anyways. That means a separate build target, so no need to keep bitcode enabled in the iOS target just for Watch OS. However there are of course other reasons to keep it enabled when building for iOS.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Found this recently, which seems to imply that you need to enable bitcode for each framework.

> "Xcode 7 has a ENABLE_BITCODE option to embed bitcode in apps, app
>   extensions, and frameworks. The option is turned on by default for iOS
>   and is mandatory for watchOS projects submitted to the store. When
>   bitcode is enabled for a target, all the objects, static libraries and
>   user frameworks used when linking that target must contain bitcode.
>   Otherwise, an error or a warning will be issued by the linker. (Note:
>   missing bitcode is currently a warning for iOS, but it will become an
>   error in an upcoming beta release of Xcode 7.) ENABLE_BITCODE should
>   be consistently turned on for all the targets. If you use a library or
>   framework provided by a third party, please contact the vendor for an
>   updated version which contains bitcode." Dear God, do we need to wait
>   for all libs to update? :S

Source ([link](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9682671))

If you don't plan to support Apple Watch you can turn off the option by searching for BITCODE in the project and the target. Change the option to No.

[image: bitcode]

Comment: thank you for reply, is there any option to turn it off?

Comment: @Kiran, yes just click under where it says the project target in the Enable Bitcode line and select "No"

Comment: I love finding the exact answer I need EXACTLY when I need it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to run the [AudioModem](https://github.com/applidium/AudioModem) code (set to target iOS 5.1) on an iOS 9.1 device. For me, simply [changing the deployment target](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW47) of the app to 9.0 (incredibly!) worked (somehow without introducing other errors?!).

Comment: The OP explicitly aksed for a solution without changing the deployment target.